# How do I add an additional condition to a WHERE Clause in a SQL Query?

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

I have a following SQL query where results are returned if a first name or last name of a fighter is entered. I need to add to this SQL query to return results if the first name and last name are also entered. Here is the query:

```
SELECT distinct
'${searchT}' searchalp,
(SELECT COUNT(fighterId) FROM tblFighter where fighter_lastName like '${searchT}%' or fighter_firstName like '${searchT}%'  ) totalresults,
A.FighterID, 
A.Fighter_FirstName, 
A.Fighter_NickName, 
if (A.Fighter_Height > 0, 
CONCAT(FLOOR(A.Fighter_Height/12), '\' ', MOD(A.Fighter_Height,12), '"'), '') Fighter_Height_inch, 
A.Fighter_NormalWeight, 
if (A.Fighter_Reach > 0, CONCAT(ROUND(A.Fighter_Reach,0), '"') , '') Fighter_Reach, 
A.Fighter_Stance,
CONCAT('/fighter/',REPLACE(REPLACE(LCASE(A.Fighter_FirstName),' ','-'),'.',''),'/',REPLACE(LCASE(A.Fighter_LastName),' ','-'),'/',A.FighterID,'/') fighterURL,
(select count(*) from tblFight_Fighter where FighterID = A.FighterID and OutcomeID  = 1) fighterCareerWins, (select count(*) from tblFight_Fighter where FighterID = A.FighterID and OutcomeID  = 2) fighterCareerLosses, (select count(*) from tblFight_Fighter where FighterID = A.FighterID and OutcomeID  = 3) fighterCareerDraws,
fighter_lastName, FA.AccoladeDescription FROM tblFighter as A LEFT JOIN (SELECT FighterId, AccoladeDescription, AccoladeType
  FROM tblAccolade 
  JOIN tblEvent USING(EventID)
  JOIN (SELECT AccoladeID, Max(Event_Date) as MaxAccDate 
          FROM tblAccolade 
          JOIN tblEvent ON tblAccolade.EventID = tblEvent.EventID  
         WHERE AccoladeType = 'Belt' AND AccoladeDescription not like 'WEC%'
        GROUP BY AccoladeID) as tmpMaxAccDate ON tblAccolade.AccoladeID = tmpMaxAccDate.AccoladeID 
 WHERE Event_Date = MaxAccDate) as FA ON FA.FighterId = A.FighterId and FA.AccoladeType = 'Belt'  where A.fighter_lastName like '${searchT}%' or A.fighter_firstName like '${searchT}%' order by A.fighter_lastName ASC LIMIT ${stInd}, ${lstInd}
```

Here is an example of what is returned when a last name is entered into the input box:

```
<table class="wide">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>FIRST</th>
<th>LAST</th>
<th>NICKNAME</th>

<th>Ht.</th>
<th>Wt.</th>
<th>Reach</th>
<th>Stnc.</th>
<th>W</th>
<th>L</th>
<th>D</th>
<th>Belt</th>
</tr>

</thead>
<tbody><tr>
<td><a href="/fighter/scott/smith/376/">Scott</a></td>
<td><a href="/fighter/scott/smith/376/">Smith</a></td>
<td><a href="/fighter/scott/smith/376/">Hands of Steel</a></td>
<td>6' 0"</td>
<td>185 lbs</td>
<td>70"</td>
<td>Orthodox</td>
<td>4</td>

<td>6</td>
<td>0</td>
<td style="width:100px;"></td>
</tr><tr>
<td><a href="/fighter/dillon/smith/1406/">Dillon</a></td>
<td><a href="/fighter/dillon/smith/1406/">Smith</a></td>
<td><a href="/fighter/dillon/smith/1406/"></a></td>
<td>6' 0"</td>
<td>170 lbs</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>

<td>1</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
<td style="width:100px;"></td>
</tr><tr>
<td><a href="/fighter/maurice/smith/19/">Maurice</a></td>
<td><a href="/fighter/maurice/smith/19/">Smith</a></td>
<td><a href="/fighter/maurice/smith/19/"></a></td>
<td>6' 2"</td>
<td>221 lbs</td>

<td></td>
<td>Orthodox</td>
<td>6</td>
<td>3</td>
<td>0</td>
<td style="width:100px;"></td>
</tr><tr>
<td><a href="/fighter/david/smith/1236/">David</a></td>
<td><a href="/fighter/david/smith/1236/">Smith</a></td>
<td><a href="/fighter/david/smith/1236/"></a></td>
<td></td>

<td>155 lbs</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td>2</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>0</td>
<td style="width:100px;"></td>
</tr><tr>
<td><a href="/fighter/eric/smith/1027/">Eric</a></td>
<td><a href="/fighter/eric/smith/1027/">Smith</a></td>
<td><a href="/fighter/eric/smith/1027/"></a></td>

<td></td>
<td>0 lbs</td>
<td></td>
<td>Southpaw</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>0</td>
<td style="width:100px;"></td>
</tr><tr>
<td><a href="/fighter/patrick/smith/48/">Patrick</a></td>
<td><a href="/fighter/patrick/smith/48/">Smith</a></td>

<td><a href="/fighter/patrick/smith/48/"></a></td>
<td>6' 2"</td>
<td>225 lbs</td>
<td></td>
<td>Orthodox</td>
<td>4</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>0</td>
<td style="width:100px;"></td>
</tr><tr>
<td><a href="/fighter/adam/smith/1269/">Adam</a></td>

<td><a href="/fighter/adam/smith/1269/">Smith</a></td>
<td><a href="/fighter/adam/smith/1269/"></a></td>
<td></td>
<td>0 lbs</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td>0</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>0</td>
<td style="width:100px;"></td>
</tr><tr>
<td><a href="/fighter/josh/smith/1121/">Josh</a></td>

<td><a href="/fighter/josh/smith/1121/">Smith</a></td>
<td><a href="/fighter/josh/smith/1121/"></a></td>
<td>6' 0"</td>
<td>155 lbs</td>
<td></td>
<td>Orthodox</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>0</td>
<td style="width:100px;"></td>

</tr></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What type of database is this?

Comment: @octopusgrabbus the "poorly design" type. That query is a mess.

Comment: -1 For pasting a complete mess of a query in and just commenting "That does not work" on the answers.

Comment: You have too much business logic in your query...

Comment: I think I have been clear. I want to some how add to this query that if a user enters the first name and last name the query will return results. I just want to add that to this query. What is so hard to understand?

Comment: I just want to make a comment on those who have voted down this question. I know I am trying to solve a difficult specific issue. Just because you may not understand does not mean what I am trying to say has value. I am working on solving this issue and not just waiting on an answer from SO. I know part of the problem I have with this issue is that right now the query is only set up to except one value. So if the last name or first name is entered results are returned. But if a first name or last name is entered and then a space is enter then there are no results returned.

Answer (score 2):

In the final line simply change:

where A.fighter_lastName like '${searchT}%' or A.fighter_firstName like '${searchT}%'

to use AND instead of OR

Answer (score 1):

Modify line three above to have an AND in it:

```
(SELECT COUNT(fighterId) FROM tblFighter where fighter_lastName like '${searchT}%' AND fighter_firstName like '${searchT}%'  ) totalresults,
```

That should fix you problem.

Edit:
If you want to modify your query to accept two names in one field "John Doe" (thus you would search for a first name of John and a last name of Doe), you will need to split the string on the space and do a different WHERE clause.  You could try to pu some logic in the existing WHERE clause or you could call a different query.  However, as it has been pointed out, you are doing way too much business logic inside your SQL statement.  Try bringing this processing into your code's business layer.  For example, the one name verses two names you are describing could be determined much more easily in your code.  Then you could modify the call accordingly.

Comment: @Mojaray2k - have you considered describing *in what way* the suggestion doesn't work? Has it altered the results you're receiving? If so, in what way(s) has it improved results, and in what way(s) has it been detrimental? You're the only one who can run these queries, so just putting "that does not work" doesn't help anyone correct their answers. Alternatively, post table definitions, sample data, current results and expected results, so that others *can* run their queries and test them before posting them as answers.

Comment: Hold up. All I was just asking is. How can I make it so if a user wants to return results of a query if the first name and last name is entered. Right now the results of the query are returned if there is a first name or a last name. How is this so confusing?

Comment: @Mojaray2k - well, it's looking at the moment like 5-6 people are confused, and no-one else has supplied an answer, so I'd suggest you need to add more to your question - *some* example(s) of what you're currently getting, and what you need instead?

Comment: @Mojaray2k - I updated my post to reflect what I believe you are saying.  Can you review it and let me know what you think?

Comment: No this does not solve the problem. The current WHERE statement is fine. I need to add to it so that when a user enters a value like John Smith it returns the same value like when they enter John or Smith which is how the sql statement is set up now. I appreciate your help.